# How to use different parameter for sorting and coloring other than value

Tags: anychart

I want to sort my treemap from value but i need to set color with field change in my data but I didn't find any solution. currently both things are working with value.

This is my code:

```
<script>
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
    // The data used in this sample can be obtained from the CDN
    // https://cdn.anychart.com/samples/tree-map-charts/acme-products-by-revenue/data.json
    anychart.data.loadJsonFile('http://localhost:31066/hmdata.aspx', function (data) {
    // makes tree from the data for the sample
    var dataTree = anychart.data.tree(data, 'as-table');
    var chart = anychart.treeMap(dataTree);

    // sets title for chart and customizes it
    chart.title()
            .enabled(true)
            .useHtml(true)
            .padding([0, 0, 20, 0])
            .text(
                    'Top ACME Products by Revenue<br/>' +
                    '<span style="color:#212121; font-size: 13px;">(average sales during the year, in $)</span>'
            );

    // sets scale
    var scale = anychart.scales.ordinalColor([
        { less: 1000000},
        { from: 1000001, to: 2000000 },
        { from: 2000001, to: 3000000 },
        { from: 3000001, to: 4000000 },
        { from: 4000001, to: 5000000 },
        { greater: 5000001}
    ]);

    // sets colors for scale
    scale.colors(['#aa2121', '#c84040', '#ed7171', '#7ec17e', '#518651', '#215e2c']);

    // sets chart settings
    chart.padding([10, 10, 10, 20])
            // setting the number of levels shown
            .maxDepth(2)
            .selectionMode('none')
            .colorScale(scale)
            .hovered({fill: '#bdbdbd'});

    // enable HTML for labels
    chart.labels().useHtml(true);

    // configure labels
    chart.labels().format(function () {
        return "<div style='font-weight:bold;color:white;'>" + this.getData('name')                + "</div><br />" +
               "<div style='font-size:50%;font-weight:bold;color:white;'>" + this.getData('price') + "</div><br />" +
               "<div style='font-size:40%;color:white;'>" + this.getData('change')                 + " </div>" +
               "<div style='font-size:40%;color:white;'>(" + this.getData('pchange')               + "%)</div><br />" +
               "<div style='font-size:40%;color:white;'>" + anychart.format.number(Math.round(this.getData('value') / 100000) / 10, { groupsSeparator: ',' }) + " mn</div>";
    });

    // sets settings for headers
    chart.headers().format(function () {
        return this.getData('name');
    });
    chart.normal().headers().fontColor("#000000");
    chart.normal().headers().fontSize("6");
    chart.normal().headers().fontWeight('bold');
    chart.hovered().headers().fontColor("#000099");

    chart.labels().adjustFontSize(true);
    // sets settings for tooltip
    chart.tooltip()
            .useHtml(true)
            .titleFormat(function () {
                return '<span style="color: #ffffff;font-size:80%;">' + this.getData('name') + " - " + this.getData('companyname') + '</span>';
            })
            .format(function () {
                return '<span style="color: #ffffff;font-size:80%;">Price: ' +
                        anychart.format.number(this.getData('price'), { groupsSeparator: ',' }) +
                    '</span><br /><span style="color: #ffffff;font-size:80%;">Change: ' +
                        anychart.format.number(this.getData('change'), { groupsSeparator: ',' }) +
                    '</span><br /><span style="color: #ffffff;font-size:80%;">% Change: ' +
                        anychart.format.number(this.getData('pchange'), { groupsSeparator: ',' }) +
                    '%</span><br /><span style="color: #ffffff;font-size:80%;">Volume: ' +
                        anychart.format.number(this.value, { groupsSeparator: ',' }) + '</span>'
            });

    // set container id for the chart
    chart.container('container');
    // initiate chart drawing
    chart.draw();
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can color the chart right from the data as [this sample describes](https://playground.anychart.com/Kogc70UH).
Or using a fill function, for details check [the sample](https://playground.anychart.com/89ZvIYXj).
As a default, the chart use linear or ordinal colorscale, [the article describes this approach](https://docs.anychart.com/Basic_Charts/Treemap_Chart#color_scale).